# How to edit an modify objects in an arraylist within a different method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods

I want to be able to modify the different attributes of the elements that are stored within my array list called list. However, I need to be able to do this within my sell command. For example I would want to accept in the sell method the name of the item and the amount that user would want to sell. Then I would need to set within the sell command the new quantity I believe. I am coming up short on how to edit anything on the array list within the new method. Any help would be great.

```
package control;

import java.util.ArrayList;    
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;    
import inventory.Item;
import inventory.itemType;
/*** @author valam      */
public class Driver {
    double myBalance;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();

        list.add(new Item("Ketchup", 1.00, 10, 2.00, itemType.FOOD));
        list.add(new Item("Mayo", 2.00, 20, 3.0, itemType.FOOD));
        list.add(new Item("Bleach", 3.00, 30, 4.00, itemType.CLEANING));
        list.add(new Item("Lysol", 4.00, 40, 5.00, itemType.CLEANING));

        for(Item i : list) {
            System.out.println(i.getName());
            System.out.println(i.getQty());
        }
    }

    public static void sell(String itemName, int amount) {      
    /*String Answer1 = 
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("What would you like to sell (options: Ketchup, Mayo, Bleach, or Lysol").toLowerCase();
    String Answer2 =
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much of said item would you like to sell").toLowerCase();
    */      
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `Map<String,  Item>` to build data

Comment: I am sorry I am kind of new to java what do you mean by that

Comment: Your sell method has no access to the list of items, to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

use `Map<String, Item>` to save your item data

```
public class Driver {
    private static Map<String, Item> map = new HashMap<String, Item>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        map.put("Ketchup", new Item("Ketchup", 1.00, 10, 2.00, itemType.FOOD));
        map.put("Mayo", new Item("Mayo", 2.00, 20, 3.0, itemType.FOOD));
        map.put("Bleach", new Item("Bleach", 3.00, 30, 4.00, itemType.CLEANING));
        map.put("Lysol", new Item("Lysol", 4.00, 40, 5.00, itemType.CLEANING));
    }

    public static void sell(String itemName, int amount){
        //if itemName is 'Ketchup', you can get Item("Ketchup", 1.00, 10, 2.00, itemType.FOOD)
        Item item = map.get(itemName);
        item.setAmount(amount);
    }
}
```

Use of objects is better, if you not use `static`
`Map<String, Integer>` to record name and array index

```
public class Driver {
    private Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public Driver(List<Item> items){
        this.items = items;
        //use map to record index
        for(int index=0; index<items.size(); index++){
            this.map.put(items.get(index).getName(), index);
        }
    }

    public void sell(String itemName, int amount){
        if(map.containsKey(itemName)){
            int index = this.map.get(itemName);
            this.items.get(index).setAmount(amount);
        }
    }

    public Item getItem(String itemName){
        int index = this.map.get(itemName);
        return this.items.get(index);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();

        list.add(new Item("Ketchup", 1.00, 10, 2.00, itemType.FOOD));
        list.add(new Item("Mayo", 2.00, 20, 3.0, itemType.FOOD));
        list.add(new Item("Bleach", 3.00, 30, 4.00, itemType.CLEANING));
        list.add(new Item("Lysol", 4.00, 40, 5.00, itemType.CLEANING));

        Driver driver = new Driver(list);
        driver.sell("Ketchup", 100);
        Item item = driver.getItem("Ketchup");
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like I kind of understand where you are going with this but am still really confused. I edited my thing about so it looks more like this. But I still do not really understand what is supposed to happen and I am getting errors.

Comment: sell("ketchup", 10);
 }
 
 public static void sell(String itemName, int amount) {
  
  
  Item item = Map.get(itemName);

Comment: @VictorAlam I forget add `static` at `Map<String, Item>`

Comment: I think mapping the item name to an index in the list is over-engineering and it's just adding an additional unnecessary step and data structure to your first option. If a map can be used, use it to map the items; if a list is a must (meaning no map) then sort it and use a binary search.